# Emacs Lisp expression for matching beginning of filename in `auto-mode-alist`

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to associate filenames like "Makefile.OSX" with `makefile-mode`.

I've tried various combinations such as:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\^Makefile" . makefile-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\`Makefile" . makefile-mode))
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex specified as part of `auto-mode-alist` matches against the full pathname, so both of your regular expressions will never match against anything.

You probably want to use something like

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("Makefile.*\\'" . makefile-mode))
```

or

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/Makefile.*\\'" . makefile-mode))
```